# Getting Click Position on Plane y=0

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to get the coordinates that the user clicks on on the plane y=0

I'm doing this by unprojecting the mouse coordinates to get the world coordinates on the near and far planes then using linear interpolation to find the coordinates on the plane but it's not giving me the correct coordinates.

My unprojection code:

```
    int viewport[4];
    double modelview[16];
    double projection[16];

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

    double x, y, z;
    //x_ and y_ are the x and y coordinates of the mouse
    gluUnProject(x_, viewport[3] - y_, 0.0, modelview, projection, viewport, &x, &y, &z);
    near.x = x;
    near.y = y;
    near.z = z;
    gluUnProject(x_, viewport[3] - y_, 100.0, modelview, projection, viewport, &x, &y, &z);
    far.x = x;
    far.y = y;
    far.z = z;

    float t = -near.y / (far.y - near.y);
    target_.y = 0.0f;
    target_.x = near.x - t * (far.x - near.x);
    target_.z = near.z - t * (far.z - near.z);

    std::cout << target_ << std::endl;
```

but this always outputs:
x: a value between +-1 which seems to have a correlation to the click position just normalized even though I'm not normalizing anywhere
y: 0
z: -2

which I can't make sense of

### Edit

Sorry, the error was me doing the unprojections before my transformations which you can't tell from the above code. I have solved it now.

Comment: In order that this question not appear to remain unanswered, post your edit as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I tried but I don't have the reputation to post an answer on my own question until 8 hours has passed, which is why I came back, I just have to wait two days now to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the error was me doing the unprojections before my transformations which you can't tell from the above code.